# Launching task on queue that is first available to run

Tags: slurm

I am using an hpc which uses two different queues for nodes with slightly different hardware. For my applications they are pretty much equivalent. However, I have to launch a task on one queue or the other. Sometimes one queue will start running much earlier. Is there an easy way to automatically launch on the queue that will run first. For example, a crude way to do this would be to launch the task on both queues with a modified task that starts by killing its "twin" task so that only the first task to start actually runs. Is there some better way to do this?

Comment: You can put more than one partition to be considered in the `sbatch` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do that is to provide a list of partitions to the job. From the [documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html#OPT_partition):

> If the job can use more than one partition, specify their names in a comma separate list and the one offering earliest initiation will be used with no regard given to the partition name ordering (although higher priority partitions will be considered first)

If this is somehow forbidden or prevented, you then can implement sibling killing by specifying a job name and `--dependency=singleton`. The latter makes sure no two jobs with the same name can start at the same time. Then, at the beginning of the job script, write

scancel --name=$SLURM_JOB_NAME --state=pending

This will cancel all jobs with the same name, that are still pending.